# Regex - Conditional based on first part of text

Tags: javascript, regex

Is it possible to make a conditional that does not check part of the string when is not needed?

For example:

Regex:
`^[a-zA-Z]+.*#[0-9]+$`

Example text:
`feature: My name is Oliver #9123`

I would like to when the text being:

`release: My name is oliver`

The same Regex matches both cases not requiring the #9123 for the release prefix, is that possible?

I have tried to use some regex conditionals that I found on google, but didn't have success.

Comment: something like this? https://regex101.com/r/1Plw3c/1
ive made the final numbers optional in their own group - ? is the optional marker

Comment: @akash kind of, but just making the final numbers optional if the prefix is release.

Comment: like this? https://regex101.com/r/YY4MSf/1

Comment: If you only have feature: and release `^(?:feature:\s*[a-zA-Z].*#[0-9]+|release:.*)$` https://regex101.com/r/UX5b9L/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is an optional group:

```
^[a-zA-Z\s]+(#[0-9]+)?$
```

So that, the following strings will match:

```
"My name is Oliver #9123"
"My name is Oliver"
```

And this won't:

```
"This is not valid #xxx"
```

[Regex playground](https://regex101.com/r/AZ4ZwF/1)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you, you want the regex to work on part of the whole string,
then  you can create a function that splits the string into two parts - the part that will be checked by the regex and the part that won't be checked - then you can pass the part of the string to regex.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a logical OR (`|`) in the regexp:

```js
const tests=["My name is Oliver #9123",
             "release: My name is oliver",
             "this should fail",
             "#12345 another fail"];

tests.forEach(str=>
  console.log(str+" - "+(str.match(/^release|[a-zA-Z]+.*#[0-9]+/)?"pass":"fail"))
)
```